# nio4r gem failed to build with native extensions (trying to install redmine_knowledgebase plugin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine, bitnami

Downloaded and installed Redmine from last Linux bitnami installer (4.2) on Ubuntu server 20.04.
No issue with installation, redmine is up and running correctly:

```
  Redmine version                4.2.0.stable
  Ruby version                   2.5.8-p224 (2020-03-31) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  5.2.5
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
```

However when trying to install knowledgebase plugin i get compiler build error with nio4r gem:

`bruno@Vostro:~/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins$ git clone git://github.com/alexbevi/redmine_knowledgebase.git`

`bundle install --no-deployment`

*The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32.
The dependency ffi (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32.*

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.....
Fetching rake 13.0.3
Installing rake 13.0.3
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Fetching i18n 1.8.9
Installing i18n 1.8.9
Fetching minitest 5.14.4
Installing minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
Fetching activesupport 5.2.5
Installing activesupport 5.2.5
Using builder 3.2.4
Fetching erubi 1.10.0
Installing erubi 1.10.0
Fetching mini_portile2 2.5.0
Installing mini_portile2 2.5.0
Fetching racc 1.5.2
Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
Fetching nokogiri 1.11.2 (x86_64-linux)
Installing nokogiri 1.11.2 (x86_64-linux)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Fetching loofah 2.9.0
Installing loofah 2.9.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Fetching actionview 5.2.5
Installing actionview 5.2.5
Using rack 2.2.3
Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
Installing rack-test 1.1.0
Fetching actionpack 5.2.5
Installing actionpack 5.2.5
Fetching nio4r 2.5.7

Installing nio4r 2.5.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/bruno/redmine-4.2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.7/ext/nio4r
/home/bruno/redmine-4.2.0-0/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210329-18642-1yfhj63.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for linux/aio_abi.h... yes
checking for linux/io_uring.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for port_event_t in poll.h... no
checking for sys/epoll.h... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for port_event_t in port.h... no
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/bruno/redmine-4.2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.7/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/bruno/redmine-4.2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.7/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bytebuffer.c
compiling monitor.c
compiling nio4r_ext.c
In file included from nio4r_ext.c:6:
../libev/ev.c:2136:31: warning: ‘ev_default_loop_ptr’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
2136 | EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; / needs to be initialised to make it a definition
despite extern */
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../libev/ev.c: In function ‘ev_time’:
../libev/ev.c:2172:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
2172 | return EV_TS_GET (ts);
| ^~~~~~
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See for instructions.
make: *** [Makefile:243: nio4r_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/bruno/redmine-4.2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.7 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/home/bruno/redmine-4.2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/nio4r-2.5.7/gem_make.out_

An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.5.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install nio4r -v '2.5.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
redmine_crm was resolved to 0.0.54, which depends on
rails was resolved to 5.2.5, which depends on
actioncable was resolved to 5.2.5, which depends on nio4r
```

Same compiler build errors when trying to install gem nio4r directly before bundling:

```
gem install nio4r -v '2.5.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

.../gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/nio4r-2.5.7/mkmf.log error log:

```
...
conftest.c:6:9: error: unknown type name ‘port_event_t’
...
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: sys/event.h: No such file or directory
...
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: port.h: No such file or directory
...
```

Any insights ?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are missing some kind of linux dev libraries...  Try installing libevent-dev  first...

Comment: Thank's @AleksandarPavić but i don't know how to install libevent-dev on bitnami redmine stack restricted environment. I presume apt-get install libevent-dev is not the good way. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to install the plugin in a fresh instance of Ubuntu 20 using Bitnami Redmine 4.1.X (knowledgebase plugin doesn't officially supports Redmine 4.2) with the plugin's [installation’s commands](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/redmine/configuration/install-plugins/) after loading the Bitnami console. Could you please try the plugin's installation following these commands:

```
cd INSTALLDIR
./use_redmine
. ./scripts/setenv.sh
cd apps/redmine/htdocs/
bundle install
bundle exec ./bin/rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_knowledgebase RAILS_ENV=production
INSTALLDIR/ctlscript.sh restart
```